Why are we able to change class object inside const member function
Vector2 Add (const Vector2& other) const
{
    return Vector2(x+ other.x, y+ other.y);
}

The function is a member of the Vector2 class.
If the function is const meaning that it promises not to transform the class, why do we then return that type but can still add stuff to it? I'm genuinely confused by this. Need some clarity, thanks.

Is that inside of a class definition scope? Otherwise the const is irrelevant.

Its in a Vector2 class yes

@BeardlessDev Post a [mcve] please. The function returns another instance of Vector2 no Manipulation of the class unstance itself is done there.

" but can still add stuff to it?..." You're not adding stuff to it. You're creating an object using a constructor and then returning that object.

The code doesn't modify either *this  or other. It creates a brand new Vector2, that is not const.

@BeardlessDev As I said in the answer below also, when you wrote Vector2(x+ other.x, y+ other.y) you're not actually modifying the object but instead creating a new object using the parameterized ctor and then returning that object.

@KarlKnechtel I don't think, that dupe will answer OP's query. They actually seem to know that inside the body of a const member function we can't change a class object. The question they're asking is that they seem to think that return Vector2(x+ other.x, y+ other.y); somehow looks like it is changing the properties of the object.

@user12002570 ... wait, what? I genuinely can't understand how it's possible to think that using a constructor, i.e. the thing that specifically exists in order to create a new instance, would modify *this from inside a member function. Are you quite sure that this is OP's misconception? (It matters because, assuming that this could possibly be something that someone else could think, the question needs to be edited such that it accurately reflects that misconception - with correct terminology.)

@KarlKnechtel It might not look possible to you/me(as we're experienced c++ users). But It is possible that a newcomer/beginner might not know all the details and might think that the object is changing in that return statement. I mean we should be open to other people's thinking. The question might looks silly/really simple to us(experienced users) but someone who is very new to c++, the syntax might suggest that the object is changing. I am just saying some possiblities and being open to such possibilities. The question is about confirming to the OP that the object is not actually changing.

It's not possible to correct a misconception properly without understanding what the underlying thought process is.

The question is perfectly clear about what OP is asking(at least to me). And the dupes are not applicable.


why do we then return that type but can still add stuff to it?

You're not actually modifying the current class object in any way. Instead  when you wrote Vector2(x+ other.x, y+ other.y) you're creating another object of the class type using the parameterized ctor with x+ other.x and y+ other.y as arguments and then returning that another object.

When someone is confused they are not necessarilly confused in the sense of making logical deductions from an erroneous assumption, sometimes they are just confused and aren't thinking particularly logically at all. All that is needed is a clear explanation.

@john Yes, it is important to clear OP's understanding about the fact that the return statement that uses the ctor is not actually changing the object. That is the aim of my answer. And the dupes are not applicable so I've reopened.


If the function is const meaning that it promises not to transform the class, why do we then return that type but can still add stuff to it?

Here's your misconception: the class
const prevents to modify the current class >>instance<< (*this), but not to create another class instance and return that by value.
Basically that code could be rewritten like this (probably optimized by the compiler for the same results):
Vector2 Add (const Vector2& other) const
{
    Vector2 result = 
        Vector2(this->x+ other.x, this->y+ other.y);
    return result;
}

That maybe is clearer about what's actually going on.
